# How To Reset or Clear or Undo DrawLine in Java

Tags: java, graphics

Please consider the following sample image :

[image: http://i61.tinypic.com/ehlr1x.jpg.]

All the objects (rectangles, shapes, texts, etc..) are written in `BufferedImage`. My questions is, after I write a `graphics.drawline(..)` on top of them, how to undo, or reset or clear the line(s) I created. Even if I re-execute the initialization of my graph, the lines that I drew are still there.

I can still capture the coordinates of the lines. If it is a plain background I can just re-draw it with the same background. But, in this case, this wont work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to undo things that you do with Graphics. But there are other things you can do instead with which you can get your image back.

1. Keep a copy of image before you do anything which you might want to undo.
   And redraw it when required.
2. Keep a clip image of the area of image before you do anything which you might want to undo. And redraw that area when required.

*To keep a **Stack** of these images of limited size will be a good idea to undo back in series. Don't make the stack size too big because it will consume your heap memory*

Comment: I don't think so. Just have an instance `Stack<Image> stack` in your code. Suppose you have an instance `BufferedImage bi` which will be drawn on screen on calling `repaint()`. And you draw something over it. But before drawing something **undoable** create another `BufferedImage copy` and draw `bi` over `copy`, insert it into stack : `stack.push(copy)`. And whenever you want to undo, do this : `bi = stack.pop()`.

Comment: @rainbowsix You can accept an answer if you find it helpful (specifically most helpfull) by clicking on tick icon which earn the poster 15 repo and acceptor 2 repo.  You will be able to upvote any answer that you think is good once you get enough repo i.e. 15

Comment: I have tried this but still getting not enough memory...ahhh..:(:(

Comment: I don't understand. I don't think you will go short of memory. Were you reading too many images or are you creating too many images??? If you are keeping so much images in stack then you should keep checking the size of stack and whenever you add an image into it and your stack crosses the size limit, then remove 1 image from `rear` end. And another approach is to use java command line option to increase heap memory.

Comment: I mean not enough on heap memory.. Yes, too many shapes and text.. Imagine a city map that has all forms of sizes and text, then reset, then clear, then reload..Again, reset, then reload.....etc...

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer using deep copy :)

So, first, I deep copied the original or default image. Then, If I write something on the original I overwrite it with the back up copied (deep copied again)..

```
static BufferedImage deepCopy(BufferedImage bi) {
    ColorModel cm = bi.getColorModel();
    boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
    WritableRaster raster = bi.copyData(null);
    return new BufferedImage(cm, raster, isAlphaPremultiplied, null);
}
```

Complete code can be found [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1269489?start=0&tstart=0)..